# objective c ios http request sent not encoded string

Tags: objective-c, ios, request

Is it possible to set as http body not encoded string?

```
  NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

  NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

  [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
  [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
  NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]];
  [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
  [request setHTTPBody:postString];
```

I had tried  this and got an error :
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Have you tried it? My guess is that it will work.

Comment: You have to post data, and there is no reason to set the Content-Length as it will be set based on the body.

Comment: From NSURLRequest

- (NSData *)HTTPBody

Answer (score 0):

```
[request setHTTPBody:postString];
```

should be

```
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: Actually this answer is kinda right. At least it helped me a lot! The setHTTPBody method takes an NSData object and not an NSString object. So you'll have to encode the HTTPBody string object into an NSData object with [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] or NSASCIIStringEncoding.